# reverse array in range in C

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, if-statement, reverse

I have to solve it in C language. I have arrays with n integers. L and U are lower and upper bound. I have to reverse numbers in array which is in [L,U]. I tried it by this way, but in some cases the answer is wrong. What mist be changed in the code? Or is there any other logic to complete the task?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int x, arr[100], n, l, u, a, temp, temp1;
  scanf("%d%d%d", &n, &l, &u);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &x); // read elements of an array
    arr[i] = x;
  }
  a = n / 2;
  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    for (int j = a; j < n; j++) {
      if (arr[i] >= l && arr[i] <= u) {
        if (arr[j] >=l && arr[j] < u) {
          temp = arr[j];
          temp1 = arr[i];
          arr[i] = temp;
          arr[j] = temp1;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
  }
}
```

sample input:
10(number of integers) -7(lower bound) 5(upper bound)
-10 -9 5 -2 -3 7 10 6 -8 -5

sample output:
-10 -9 -5 -3 -2 7 10 6 -8 5

my output:
-10 -9 -5 -2 -3 7 10 6 -8 5

Comment: Are `l` and `u` supposed to represent array indices or values?

Comment: Please show sample input and the expected output.

Comment: they might be any number, user inputs is

Comment: But what are they lower and upper bounds of? The problem description sounds like they're bounds of indexes, but you're comparing them to values.

Comment: I don't understand why you have nested loops. The outer loop iterates over the first half of the array, the inner loop iterates over the second half of the array. What does that have to do with reversing elements?

Comment: Get a pointer to the first element of the array, and a pointer to the last element you've input in the array. Then in a single non-nested loop swap the values where these pointers work. Increase the first pointer, decrease the second pointer. End loop when both pointers are the same, or pass each other.

Comment: I am trying to swap the array in concrete range and I am going from the beginning and bottom to swap their places. see my sample input/output and it will be more understandable.

Comment: For your sample input, please separate the size, upper bound and lower bound from the values you then read into the array.

Comment: My pointer solution could still work. Just increase the first pointer until it gets to the first value in the [L, U] range, and do the same for the second pointer (but decrease it instead). Swap the values that the pointers are pointing to. Then search for the next value in the range [L, U].  End, as before, when the pointers are equal or passes each other. One outer loop, two inner loops for finding the next values. Once `if` to check for the pointers passing each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a valiant attempt. Your nested `for()` loops are appropriate for some kinds of sorting algorithms, but not for what seems to be the purpose of this task.

From the sample input and desired output, you really want to establish a 'bracket' at either end of the array, then shift both toward the centre, swapping elements whose value happens to satisfy
 `low <= n <= high` value. (In this case, -7 <= n <= 5).

Here's a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int swap( int arr[], size_t l, size_t r ) { // conventional swap algorithm
    int t = arr[l];
    arr[l] = arr[r];
    arr[r] = t;
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { -10, -9, 5, -2, -3, 7, 10, 6, -8, -5, }; // your data
    size_t i, sz = sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0];

    for( i = 0; i < sz; i++ ) // showing original version 
        printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

#define inRange( x ) ( -7 <= arr[x] && arr[x] <= 5 ) // a good time for a macro

    size_t L = 0, R = sz - 1; // 'L'eft and 'R'ight "brackets"
    do {
        while( L < R && !inRange( L ) ) L++; // scan from left to find a target
        while( L < R && !inRange( R ) ) R--; // scan from right to find a target
    } while( L < R && swap( arr, L, R ) && (L+=1) > 0 && (R-=1) > 0 );

    for( i = 0; i < sz; i++ ) // showing results
        printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

```
-10 -9 5 -2 -3 7 10 6 -8 -5
-10 -9 -5 -3 -2 7 10 6 -8 5
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an `O(N)` solution that does not require nesting of loops.

First, with the code as you as you have it, declare an additional array and some other helper variables that keeps track of what indices need to be swapped.

```
  int left, right;
  int swaplist[100] = {0};
  int swapcount = 0;
```

Your can keep your initial intake loop exactly as you have it, but amended to append the **index** of the newly scanned value to the `swaplist` array if the value is between the lower and upper bounds.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &x); // read elements of an array
    arr[i] = x;

    if ((x >= l) && (x <= u)) {
        swaplist[swapcount++] = i;
    }
  }
```

Then a single loop to iterate over "swaplist" and do the swaps against the original array.

```
  left = 0;
  right = swapcount-1;
  while (left < right) {
      int leftindex = table[left];
      int rightindex = table[right];

      int tmp = arr[leftindex];
      arr[leftindex] = arr[rightindex];
      arr[rightindex] = tmp;
      left++; right--;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the assignment correctly you need to reverse elements of an array that satisfy some condition.

If so then these nested for loops

```
  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    for (int j = a; j < n; j++) {
      if (arr[i] >= l && arr[i] <= u) {
        if (arr[j] >=l && arr[j] < u) {
          temp = arr[j];
          temp1 = arr[i];
          arr[i] = temp;
          arr[j] = temp1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

do not make sense.

It is enough to use only one for loop as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 1, 10, 2, 3, 20, 4, 30, 5, 40, 6, 7, 50, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    int l = 10, u = 50;

    for (size_t i = 0, j = N; i < j; i++ )
    {
        while (i < j && !( l <= a[i] && a[i] <= u )) ++i;

        if (i < j)
        {
            while (i < --j && !( l <= a[j] && a[j] <= u ));

            if (i < j)
            {
                int tmp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
1 10 2 3 20 4 30 5 40 6 7 50 9
1 50 2 3 40 4 30 5 20 6 7 10 9
```

You could write a separate function as for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse_in_range( int a[], size_t n, int low, int upper )
{
    for (size_t i = 0, j = n; i < j; )
    {
        while (i < j && !( low <= a[i] && a[i] <= upper )) ++i;

        if (i < j)
        {
            while (i < --j && !( low <= a[j] && a[j] <= upper ));

            if (i < j)
            {
                int tmp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = tmp;

                ++i;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 1, 10, 2, 3, 20, 4, 30, 5, 40, 6, 7, 50, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    reverse_in_range( a, N, 10,50 );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Comment: Minor grammar fix: change "do not make a sense" --> "do not make sense" or "do not make any sense" or "make no sense".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone help. I read all of them, but I found another way to solve this problem. I will write it just in case. (some variable names are random, so in case of questions, comment).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int x, main[100], n, l, u, a = 0, arr[100], temp, m = 0,f=0,c,d;
  scanf("%d%d%d", &n, &l, &u);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &x); // read elements of an array
    main[i] = x;
    if (x >= l && x <= u) {
      a++; //check if element is in range [l,u] and increasing a. later "a" will be used a length of the array "arr". this array cootains elements, which in in [u,l].
    }
  }


  //add [u,l] elements in new array "arr"
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (main[i] >= l && main[i] <= u) {
      arr[m] = main[i];
      m++; //index counter of "arr", 
    }
  }
  d=0;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(main[i]==arr[d]){
      c=arr[a-d-1];
      main[i]=c;
      d++;
    }
  }
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%d ",main[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this function should work

```
    /**
     * reverse_array - reverses an array
     * @a: pointer to array
     * @n: variable for array size
     */

     void reverse_array(int *a, int n)
     {
            int length = 0, length1, length2, actlength = n - 1;
            int arr[100];

            for (length1 = 0, length2 = 0; length1 < n; length1++, length2++)
                    arr[length1] = a[length2];

            if (n > 0)
            {
                    while (length < n)
                    {
                            a[length] = arr[actlength];
                            actlength--;
                            length++;
                    }
            }
     }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

My best guess is that scanf is very annoying, on top of that, your format is ambiguous.

How will %d%d%d read 1234? Will it give you 12 3 and 4? 1 23 and 4? ...

try to do

```
scanf("%d %d %d" ...); // or
scanf("%d, %d, %d" ...);
```

something like that. Note that scanf is not recommended to be used, getc is a neat alternative, though also annoying when you want to read numbers with more than one digit, but you could create a function read_number, which, based on getc, will read a number as a string and return the int value with stoi.

Comment: You need to read the description for scanf. And getc is not an alternative to scanf to read integers

Comment: I don't care about one downvote, but since you insist, I will clarify...
int read_int() {
    char c[32];
    // loop with getc to fill c array...
    return stoi(c);
}